# Accessing all files in a directory in a Nikola template

Tags: static-site, nikola

I'm converting a web site from Hugo to Nikola. Hugo had some way of accessing all the files in a directory. Then I was able to read their metadata, etc. Is there a way to do this in a Nikola template file (using Jinja2 perhaps)?